# What is the status of "natural" punctuation?

Tags: punctuation, commas

By natural punctuation, I mean punctuation that reflects the way the material is spoken.

I once read a very interesting article (now lost) about the history of writing and punctuation.  Word spacing and punctuation have not always existed. At one time, there was no punctuation. Later, punctuation merely reflected the pauses and stresses of speech. Still later, we have what exists today.

My point is, punctuating by speech patterns was once the natural, logical, and CORRECT  way to punctuate sentences. It was not only respectable, it was the only way.

Anyway, how much respectability does this way still have? It seems to me that many people still use it. Is it considered intellectually respectable?

Comment: How can you term something "CORRECT" that varies with the way individuals speak—that is, thoroughly idiosyncratically?

Comment: Do you have a question about English? Because it’s unclear whether you’re talking about punctuation in English or in general. For example, I’m pretty sure word spacing has always existed in English. Maybe not in Ancient Greek manuscripts written in all caps. But that’s not about English. And what exists today, in English, is still influenced by things such as pauses in speech.

Comment: Maybe I never saw the answers beginning with,"closed as unclear," until today, but now that I have, I have to wonder how anyone could say such things. Reading these comments definitely worsens my opinion of this site. Is my question unclear? Quite the contrary. I think it is a model question, and I was even going to copy it until I noticed that it was something that I had written. Great stuff!!! Keep it up, Warren. Well, I still like this site, and I won't lose it again, because I have now bookmarked it.

Comment: Upon further research, I found the answer I was looking for.  There are two basic types/philosophies of punctuation: elocutionary punctuation and syntactic punctuation. What I termed "natural" is called "elocutionary" by grammarians. While the syntactic  method rules, the elocutionary method is still respectable. Take your pick.

Comment: Ok... I think I now understand what you were trying to do. Were you trying to post an answer to your own question? Unfortunately, no one can post new answers because the question has been closed by the community as being unclear. Visit meta again, and update your most recent question and ask what you can do to post your solution in a proper answer box or how to reopen your closed Q.

Comment: Mari-Lou, I'm learning, but for anyone to say that my post was unclear is almost criminal in my opinion. Nothing could have been clearer, and I wouldn't change a word. However, I'll say no more about that. Oh, and I was just supplementing my first statement. "Natural" was my term, but as I learned more, I decided to use the words that others use: descriptive/rhetorical/elocutionary. "Natural" is good, but not if others don't use it

Answer (score 3):

Here is a compilation I've made addressing 'comma usages which aren't necessary to police syntax but are still useful'.

[Commas: Pauses, Shifts and Contrasted Coordinate Elements:                             write.com](http://www.write.com/writing-resources-articles/general-writing/punctuation/mastering-the-art-of-comma-usage/commas-pauses-shifts-and-contrasted-coordinate-elements/)

> **Pauses**
>
> Any comma essentially represents a pause – one that gives your readers
> the signal to take a quick breath before continuing with the next
> portion of the sentence. When a comma is used, it places more emphasis
> on what immediately precedes and follows the comma. Sometimes, there
> is no grammatical rule [sic, with the narrow sense of 'grammar' sensibly used on ELU] that dictates the use of a comma in a
> particular spot within a sentence, but the use of one, creating a
> pause, can create an emphasis that does not exist without the comma.
> Consider the following examples:
>
> Example 1: Yesterday, I experienced the worst day of my life.
>
> Example 2: The novice guitarist was butchering my favorite song, quite
> badly.
>
> In both examples, the comma is 'grammatically' unnecessary. It does,
> however, create a pause that places more emphasis. In the first
> example, the emphasis of the sentence shifts from “worst day of my
> life” to “yesterday” and “I.” In the second example, the emphasis is
> placed on “butchering my favorite song” and “quite badly.” You might
> do this to emphasize the extent to which the song is butchered.
>
> It is important to consider the overall meaning you are trying to
> convey with a sentence when adding a comma as a pause to emphasize
> something, as putting a comma in the wrong spot can alter the meaning
> of your sentence.
>
> [[John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/614116/punctuate-ive-had-it-cut-do-you-like-it-comma-period-dash-or-semicolo) comments on this correlating of pause and punctuation used in dialogue:
> *This is dialog, not text. Use a comma or a period or whatever seems to recreate the voice.*] –
>
> **Shifts**
>
> Sometimes sentences require your readers to shift gears in a sense.
> You might make a statement and look for confirmation by turning the
> sentence into a question. Similarly, a comma represents the shift from
> one thing to another.
>
> Example 1: You plan on watching the Super Bowl, right?
>
> Example 2: Sometimes you might feel a little nervous in new
> environments, even when you are a little excited at the same time.
>
> Both examples above represent a shift in the sentence. Using the comma
> clues your readers that the shift is about to occur, even when they
> are not consciously aware of the shift happening.
>
> **Contrasted Coordinate Elements**
>
> Normally coordinate elements do not require the use of a comma, as
> they are connecting similar items, thoughts or phrases. However, when
> the elements are contrasting, a comma is necessary to notate the
> contrast. See the below examples:
>
> Example 1: She was happy most of the day, but sad by the end of it.
>
> Example 2: She received a high mark on the exam, not the low one she
> expected.
>
> Example 3: Her dancing partner was graceful, yet clumsy with certain
> steps.
>
> In each of the examples above, the part of the sentence that comes
> after the comma contrasts the part that comes before it. Yet, both
> parts are essential to convey the intended meaning.

I believe that this is all very sage and helpful advice: accuracy and disambiguation must have the first call on the resource offered by the comma, but judiciously using commas for other purposes where no conflict will occur makes good sense.

.............

One style guru has a recommendation that speakers might really appreciate:

[One Woman Shop](http://onewomanshop.com/author/ashley-brooks/)

> Commas:  Use commas to create a pause if your breath units are getting
> too long.

Again, the caveat about the need for clarity trumps this.

.............

.............

Another source gives examples where commas mirror pauses in the spoken word that **would** be needed to prevent misunderstanding:

[UCalgary Eduweb _Punctuation       3.4J](http://www.ucalgary.ca/uofc/eduweb/grammar/course/punctuation/3_4j.htm)

> **Using Commas to Prevent Misunderstanding**
>
> Sometimes you must use a comma to make the reader pause in the
> appropriate place in the sentence in order to prevent misreading.
> Becoming a good writer means developing an awareness of how your
> sentences will sound to the reader. Reading your work aloud, to
> yourself or to a friend, is a good way to identify the places in the
> sentence where pauses--or commas--are needed.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Without comma: Before leaving the soldiers demolished the fort.
>
> A comma is needed here to prevent confusion in interpreting the
> sentence. Without the comma, the reader might think that the soldiers
> were being left, rather than doing the leaving. The sentence might
> have gone on to end this way:
>
> "Before leaving the soldiers, I kissed them all goodbye".
>
> With comma: Before leaving, the soldiers demolished the fort.
>
> Example 2:
>
> Without comma: As she was rising to speak her mind suddenly played a
> cruel trick and she forgot her speech.
>
> Is she going to "speak her mind"? The reader is likely to read the
> first part of the sentence this way, unless help arrives in the form
> of a comma.
>
> With comma: As she was rising to speak, her mind suddenly played a
> cruel trick and she forgot her speech.
>
> Example 3:
>
> Without comma: Shelley having drowned Byron presided over the funeral
> ceremonies on the beach.
>
> Did Shelley drown Byron? If so, how could Byron preside over the
> funeral?
>
> With comma: Shelley having drowned, Byron presided over the funeral
> ceremonies on the beach.
>
> One final example:
>
> Consider this question, asked by one zoo-keeper to another:
>
> Without comma: Did the lion eat Fred?
>
> With comma: Did the lion eat, Fred?
>
> There is a crucial difference between the two sentences (especially to
> Fred). Never underestimate the power of a comma!

Comment: Hey, I like this site. I'm getting ready for bed, but I liked what I saw above, and  will definitely be back. I particularly like the phrase, "natural punctuation,"  I use it myself, but it's very seldom that I run across it.

Comment: @WarrenJones to accept an answer you can click on the grey tick that lies beneath the bottom arrow. The grey tick (or "checkmark" if you're American) changes into green and the system awards you, the asker, 2 rep points. When you have "earned" 15 rep you can upvote any answer or question anywhere on the site. See this page for more info https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges (all the guidelines can be found in the help centre)