# Punctuate "I've had it cut [] do you like it?" (comma, period, dash, or semicolon)

Tags: punctuation, complex-sentences

This is from a test:

> What on earth have you done to your hair?
>
> Oh. I've had it cut, do you like it?

I am wondering if the comma after "cut" is justified. Would a period, dash, or semicolon be better in its place?

Comment: "Oh, I've had it cut. Do you like it?"

Comment: This is dialog, not text.  Use a comma or a period or whatever seems to recreate the voice.

Comment: Unless you want to be accused of the dreaded comma splicing, you should use a period, dash, or semicolon. (You can use a comma after the interjection *Oh* though.)

Comment: In speech there are no comma splices because there are no splices. Phrase follows phrase and nobody cares about your spelling.

Comment: A lot of people seem opposed to ever using semicolons or colons when punctuating speech on the grounds that nobody ever speaks a (semi)colon. But a semicolon is often used for linking closely-related sentences. You'd also want to consider whether "Do you like it?" is an afterthought said after a pause, or more closely linked. And as with any test, it depends on what you were taught in class.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a full stop (period) after “cut”. Since the next part is a new question. It wouldn’t make sense with a comma.
Though possibly there’s an argument for using an ellipsis instead . . . to represent a pause.

Comment: I guess it is the same case here:

- Here, eat some of this.
- I'd rather not, if you don't mind, I don't eat meat.

Comment: Analyses at [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385648/is-the-use-of-a-semicolon-in-the-sentence-the-south-sided-with-the-king-the-no/385677#385677) refute the 'comma splices are always unacceptable' stance. Here, Professor Lawler endorses the stop ~ pause length correlation (, < ; < ... < . < ....) (though I'd not use a comma here myself). But there _is_ less prescriptivism surrounding punctuation nowadays.